# How to change font family for metro textbox in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, microsoft-metro

I am using `metro textbox` and `metro combo box` in my windows application. When running the application, the font family of `metro textbox` and `metro combo box` looks different. But I want to change all control font family to "ARIAL".

Any suggestions or Reference?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change only the Font Family to Arial to ALL CONTROLS, this could help (you could do this in Load ou Shown events:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ChangeFontFamily(this);
}

private void ChangeFontFamily(Form _form)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < _form.Controls.Count; i++)
     {
         _form.Controls[i].Font = new Font("Arial", _form.Controls[i].Font.Size, _form.Controls[i].Font.Style);
      }
}
```